# Can I create a Stub of an Activity in Testing Project?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I want to create a stub of one of my Activities, but I want to keep it in the test project so not to have it in the actual apk. I don't seem to be able to find a way to do it though. I get this:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.test.StubActivity }

I did find if I put it in the main project and put it in the manifest accordingly (IntentFilter:(Action:Main, Category:Default)) it will work, well it actually crashed, but I am not bothered by that. Something to fix later on.

I did think about putting everything in the same main project and just have a test package, but that would then involve messing the manifest, I think. It seems better to keep them separate. It's just cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mange to find a way to do it. What you do is test a stub using ActivityUnitTestCase. What I was doing was using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 instead, and hence the error.